# How do I pass a neutral element into the cooperative groups exclusive_scan?

Tags: cuda

I'm looking at the [reduction operators](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#reduce-operators) and that isn't covered there. Neither does the [relevant section](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#inclusive-scan-and-exclusive-scan) for the scan functions explain why the neutral element argument is missing. Here is the declaration for the `exclusive_scan`:

```
template <typename TyGroup, typename TyVal, typename TyFn>
auto exclusive_scan(const TyGroup& group, TyVal&& val, TyFn&& op) -> decltype(op(val, val));
```

How could the exclusive scan possibly work without the neutral element?

Comment: It seems to be implemented as an inclusive scan followed by a `shfl_up()`. The first thread then generally returns default constructed `TyVal{}`. In case of a plus scan of integers they avoid the `shfl_up()` and instead just subtract `val` again.

Comment: What do you mean by neutral element?

Comment: @AbatorAbetor The neutral element of addition is zero, of multiplication is one and of maximum is the smallest possible value. I.e. `f(x, neutral) = x` where `f` is the binary function used for reduction or scan.

Comment: `std::exclusive_scan` also doesn't take some neutral element. Instead it has an initial value which is probably not present in cooperative groups because you can easily do `op(init, exclusive_scan(group, val, op))`, while with the STL merging that `transform` wouldn't be straightforward/elegant.

Comment: @paleonix If it just default constructs the value, then the Cuda function is basically broken for anything other than sum reduction, and I'd be better off doing an inclusive scan and shuffling up by 1, substituting the neutral element in the first thread. Or rather, I should substitute the first thread's result after an exclusive scan.

Comment: Although I see that `op(init, exclusive_scan(...))` isn't very general, because it relies on the assumption that `op(init, TyVal{}) == init` which is easily broken, e.g. for multiplication.